# Samba / Netatalk on the same folder

Tags: windows-7, osx-snow-leopard, samba, ubuntu-10.10, netatalk

I have set up a remote netatalk over ssh share for my home network (Mac only) now I want to access the files with a Windows PC. 
Netatalk gives access to the home folder of the connected user.
 Now: If I configure Samba to access the same folder, do I run the risk of messing up the files? Should I look for a way to connect Windows to Netatalk instead?

How easy is it nowadays to SSH tunnel a SMB share to Windows 7, will I still run into issues with the Netbios port? I have multiple mapped drives into the local network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine as long as two users aren't writing to the same file(s) at the same time.

SSH will provide a splendid tunnel, but another option worth considering is OpenVPN.net which, depending on what you need, may work better for you in certain ways.

Comment: Thank you - but wouldn't OpenVPN disable my LAN access?

Comment: It shouldn't.  Is there something special about your LAN that you think might interfere with it?