# Rolling Your Own Online Storage on Shared Hosting Account

Tags: network-drive, web-hosting, online-backup, online-storage

I've got a Windows-based *shared* webhosting account ( with arvixe.com - no admin/root access via RDP - all web control panels) which I used to use to host freelance (ASP.Net) projects for clients. Due to the recession I'm back working for a company full-time so no more freelance projects to host :-(  and so have virtually unlimited disk space sitting around doing nothing.

I need an online storage/backup solution and was thinking about signing up for a MobileMe account when it occurred to me that I might be able to make use of the unused space and turn all those unused gigabyte into some kind of homegrown online storage solution.

Does anyone have any suggestions of software or techniques that I could use to this end?

I don't want to access this using *only* FTP and need something that could expose itself to Windows and Macs as a network drive over the web. As a base level of functionality, I'd like to be able to backup Win/Mac machines to it. And, in an ideal world, something could stream media to iPod Touch, Android phone or other client.

Any suggestions very gratefully received.

Comment: You mentioned "shared" hosting in a comment. You might want to clarify in your question whether your webhost accounts are on your server or someone elses (that you do not have root access to). I assumed your question "Rolling Your Own Online Storage" implied the servers were yours.

Comment: Done. Please see edits above.

Answer (score 1):

I use an ubuntu 10.10 server with netatalk installed, tunneled via ssh. I then go to the finder, "Connect to server" and connect to the local mapped netatalk port. It was very easy to setup.

Also see my related question: [Samba / Netatalk on the same folder](https://superuser.com/questions/254224/samba-netatalk-on-the-same-folder)

Comment: Interesting. 

I use Windows hosting so this unfortunately isn't an option for me :-(

Comment: Using Windows I'd suggest setting up a VPN on the server and then connect with a mac client to it. Then you can connect to a SMB share using the same technique. I haven't done it myself though so I can't give you exact guidance.